# Como obtener numero de vocales en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Como puedo obtener el numero de vocales mayusculas y minusculas en una variable en JavaScript.

```
        var person = new Object();
        person = prompt("Introduce tus datos");

        //Numero de vocales
        var numVocales;

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 

            var vocal;

            if (i = 0){
                vocal = "a";
            }
            else if (i = 1){
                vocal = "e";
            }
            else if (i = 2){
                vocal = "i";
            }
            else if (i = 3){
                vocal = "o";
            }
            else if (i = 4){
                vocal = "u";
            }
            else if (i = 5){
                vocal = "A";
            }
            else if (i = 6){
                vocal = "E";
            }
            else if (i = 7){
                vocal = "I";
            }
            else if (i = 8){
                vocal = "O";
            }
            else if (i = 9){
                vocal = "U";
            }

            var aux = person.indexOf(vocal);

            if(aux != -1){
                numVocales++;
            }

        }


        alert(numVocales);
```

No logro mostrar la informacion en el alert, puede ser que tenga mal planteado el for. Ademas no se si usando indexOf() me saca la primera letra que concide.Me refiero que si tengo ana, usando indexOf() me devolveria uno o dos?

Comment: Hola Eduardo. Mas alla de que tener una construccion FOR...NEXT y adentro llenarla de IF es muy mala (para que haces el for entonces), veo que tu problema es que solo encuentras una vocal, pq no iteras por toda la cadena cada vez que encuentras una coincidencia...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La solución de Pablo Lozano te va a servir más porque es un análisis más completo de tu código. Yo te voy a poner una solución que es mucho más corta que lo que estás intentando hacer.

La idea es usar expresiones regulares para encontrar las ocurrencias de vocales (`[aeiou]`) dentro de la cadena. Las encuentra todas por el modificador `g` y no distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas por el modificador `i`.

Aquí un ejemplo:

```js
var cadena = "aAeEiIoOuU son vocales";
var numeroVocales = cadena.match(/[aeiou]/gi).length;

console.log(numeroVocales);
```

Comment: Me pareció que meter regex era demasiado *hardcore* con su nivel de programación, pero has estado certero, como de costumbre

Comment: gracias me valio la solucion, y me ahorre toda la maraña de bucle y comprobaciones

Answer (score 5):

El código tiene bastantes fallos, así que trato de enumerarlos y te dejo la tarea de arreglarlo:

```
var person = new Object();
```

Esta primera línea no te sirve de nada, puedes eliminarla, porque en la siguiente línea asignas un nuevo valor a `person`

```
person = prompt("Introduce tus datos");

//Numero de vocales
var numVocales;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
```

Este bucle no tiene mucho sentido: ¿hasta 10 porque tienes 10 posibles letras que buscar? Lo que tienes que hacer es recorrer el string que hay en `person`.

```
    var vocal;

    if (i = 0){
```

Este es un error que suele pasar desapercibido a los novatos: en lugar de usar `==` (comparar si son iguales) has usado una asignación. Eso lo que hace es que i valga 0 y que ese sea el valor a comprobar. Como 0 es "falso", pasa al siguiente if...

```
        vocal = "a";
    }
    else if (i = 1){
```

Aquí tenemos de nuevo el mismo error, asignas 1 a i, con la diferencia de que 1 es "verdadero" y se acaban las comparaciones. Esto hace que en cada iteración i valga 1 y el bucle nunca termine, colgando la ejecución. Por eso nunca se llega al `alert`.

Pista para buscar vocales:

```
let vocales='aeiouAEIOU'; 
let letras='ca';
if (vocales.indexOf(letras.charAt(0) != -1) { }
```

Comment: no seria, while vocales.indexof?? o arruine la tarea?

Comment: @gbianchi no, hay que recorrer todas las letras y **contar** las vocales

Comment: ahh ok.. vas mirando de a un caracter.. no dije nada...

Comment: gracias por la explicacion y la ayuda ;D me sirvio para entenerlo mejor gracias.